# Positioning the next and prev button on bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to use bootstrap carousel (slideshow). I copied the code and everything, but the next button is outside the slider.
the running code is here: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/barnamah/VCwPE/2/)
If you see, now the right arrow (next button) is outside the image.
I tried to put a div with row and a div with span6 or 8 but didn't work.

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span8">    
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item"><img src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-03.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-01.jpg">       
            </div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-02.jpg"> </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel nav -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- span -->
    </div>    <!-- row -->
```

What I want is to put an image on the left and a paragraph on the right on each slid and by pressing the Next and Prv button it should display.
my questions are  as follow:

1. How can I position both buttons outside the image (on the left and rigth)?
2. How can just bring the next button (right arrow) on the image like the "prev" buttton?
3. How can I normally pause it so it works only by next and prev clicks?
   thank you

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/VCwPE/6

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: false;   
})
```

1. By using the standard markup the buttons are positioned correctly. You could apply different left/right positions to move them, like I did in this fiddle.
2. See above.
3. Use interval: false

Bungus makes some good points (answer has been removed). I think you're better off using the least markup and letting your carousel be responsive, as the Bootstrap team intended.

Comment: thank you @isherwood but the first slide doesn't start working untill there is a click on "next" or "prev" here is the link [link](http://abstutor.com/tests/slide00/)